# Array Modifier Problem

Tags: modifiers

As you can see in the picture, I am trying to use Array modifier. All settings are applied as per a tutorial from youtube. But when I am rotating the empty object, it results in stairs as in the picture.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Is the Z coordinate of the empty offset object 0 ? Change it to see what happens.

Comment: What did you expect to get? And how does it look in 'orthogonal' view (keypad-5)?